# horizontal scroll bar on a div having multiple tables

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I have multiple tables in DIV element and want to give horizontal scrollbar on a certain width. how to give horizontal scroll bar on a div having multiple tables

```
    <div style="float:left; max-width:300px; min-width:50px; overflow-x:auto!important; white-space:nowrap;">
<table width="200" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="float:left">
  <tr>
    <td>test1</td>
    <td>test1</td>
    <td>test1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test1</td>
    <td>test1</td>
    <td>test1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table width="200" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="float:left!important">
  <tr>
    <td>test2</td>
    <td>test2</td>
    <td>test2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test2</td>
    <td>test2</td>
    <td>test2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, use div in div.
the sample:http://jsbin.com/opohif/2/edit

hope it could help u.

Comment: Thanks it is working for fixed no. of tables but in my case no. of tables are not fixed it is dynamically generating, there may be more than no. of 2 or 3 tables..

Comment: Please give some suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative solution find out but is there any direct option, please suggest.

```
<div style="float:left; max-width:300px; min-width:50px; overflow-x:auto!important; white-space:nowrap;">
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table width="200" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="float:left">
              <tr>
                <td>test1</td>
                <td>test1</td>
                <td>test1</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>test1</td>
                <td>test1</td>
                <td>test1</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>
            <table width="200" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="float:left!important">
              <tr>
                <td>test2</td>
                <td>test2</td>
                <td>test2</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>test2</td>
                <td>test2</td>
                <td>test2</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```